# Bind linq query to devexpress grid

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net, linq-to-entities

I write this code for bind a linq query to datasource , but this is very slow .
Please help me to speed up this action.
My database have 208 tables.

```
        var ctx = new TestEFEntities();
        var bindingObject = new BindingSource();
        var query = from accS in ctx.AccountingSides
                    join sex in ctx.Sexes on accS.SexID equals sex.SexID
                    select new
                    {
                         accS.Fname,
                         accS.Lname,
                         sex.SexName
                    };
        query.ToList().ForEach(f => bindingObject.Add(f));
        this.gridControl1.DataSource = query;
```

Comment: "but this is very slow" Have you identified what is slow about it? If you are using devexpress you should be able to use the server mode directly with Entity Framework IQueryable, for pagenation.

Comment: hi , what is server mode directly ?
I don't have any idea about this
please help me